# powerbi match some columns with some other columns in different rows

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have data:

| NAME | system 1 | system 2 | system 3 | rating 1 | rating 2 | rating 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| papa | abc | abd | abe | 50 | 25 | 25 |
| mama | abc | abd | *null* | 50 | 50 | *null* |

I need the following table as output:

| NAME | system | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| papa | abc | 50 |
| papa | abd | 25 |
| papa | abe | 25 |
| mama | abc | 50 |
| mama | abd | 50 |

I guess that unpivot can help but I can't get through.

Comment: thanks for posting the sample data as paste-able text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -- unpivot, split the name into two columns, use that new column to repivot

sample code:

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"NAME"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Attribute.1", "Attribute.2"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Split Column by Delimiter", List.Distinct(#"Split Column by Delimiter"[Attribute.1]), "Attribute.1", "Value"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Attribute.2"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Split your table into 3 NAME-system-rating tables and append them.

Comment: I have more than 3 systems and ratings, I provided only example